# Prevent the submenu hiding when clicking on the form to sign in / Change background color when parent li is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav menu which has dropdown lists, and I have two problems atm:

1. I have the menu that when you click on a parent li, it will show its submenu, and when you click on another parent li or elsewhere in the page, it will hide.

On the first li.parent, i have a login form. The code I have won't let me click on the form to enter the login details. It will hide if I click on it.

How can I fill in the login form or click on it without it being hidden? But when I click elsewhere on the page it will close?

And

2) I want to have the li.parent to change its background color when I open one of its submenu. And return to his normal background color when closing the submenu.

```js
//HEADER NAV-BAR SCRIPTS:

//Show Submenus when clicking on Parent / Hide Submenus when clicking other parent/elsewhere

function hide_sub_navs() {
        $('.parent ul').hide().removeClass("shown");
      }

      $(function() {
        hide_sub_navs();
        $(".parent").click(function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          var clicked = this;
          var sub_menu = $(clicked).find("ul");
          if (sub_menu.hasClass("shown")) {
            sub_menu.hide().removeClass("shown");
          } else {
            sub_menu.show().addClass("shown");
            $(".parent").each(function() {
              var next_li = this;
              if (next_li != clicked) {
                $(next_li).find("ul").hide().removeClass("shown");
              }
            });
          }
        });
        $(window).click(hide_sub_navs);
      });
```

```css
/** NAV MENU **/
div#nav-bar {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  width: 40%;
  clear: right;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/** Main Menu **/
div#nav-bar ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: block;
}


/** Titles **/
div#nav-bar ul li.title, li.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #005D96;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/*Change Main Menu li background when hovering*/
div#nav-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 184, 227, 0.1);
}

div#nav-bar ul li div#register li:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}

div#nav-bar ul#mainmenu li a#home {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  width: auto;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #005D96;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 28px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px; 
}


/** Submenus **/
div#nav-bar ul ul {
  height: 0 auto;
  width: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #004469;
  margin-top: 28px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: none;
}

div#nav-bar ul ul li.child-element {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

div#nav-bar ul ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  height: 27px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/** Submenu 1 - Account **/
div#nav-bar ul ul#submenu1 {
  width: 190px;
  height: 240px;
}

/*SUBMENU 1 - LOGIN FORM*/
form {
  border: none;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

form p {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  float: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

form label b {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  float: left;
  
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 208, 244, 1);
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
}

div#rememberme {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: lighter;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

div#forgotpsw p {
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  float: right;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 15px;
}

div#forgotpsw p a.forgot {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration: underline;
  width: auto;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

/*Register*/
div#register {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #00598A;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

div#register li p.register {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 10px;;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

div#register li p a.register {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFF;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: 170px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
  }
}


/** Submenu 2 - Manage Bookings **/
div#nav-bar ul ul#submenu2 {
  width: 170px;
  height: 130px;
}


/** Submenu 3 - Support **/
div#nav-bar ul ul#submenu3 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div id="nav-bar">
  <ul id="mainmenu">
     
     <li class="title"><a href="index.html" id="home" >Home</a></li>
            
            
     <li class="parent">Account
       <ul id="submenu1">
          
          <!--Login Form-->
          <form>
            <div class="container">
              <p>Log-in to Access your Account</p>
              <label><b>Username</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
                 
              <label><b>Password</b></label>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
                  
              <button type="submit">Login</button>
              
              <div id="rememberme">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked ">Remember me
                </div>
                  
              <!--Forgot Password-->
              <div id="forgotpsw">
                <li class="forgot">
                  <p>Forgot <a class="forgot" href="forgot.html">Password</a> ?</p>
                </li>
              </div>
             </div>
            </form>
              
            <!--Register-->
            <div id="register">
              <li>
                <p class="register">Don't have an account yet? Click 
                <a class="register" href="register.html">here</a> to Register.</p>
              </li>
            </div>
              
          </ul>
         </li>
            
         <li class="parent">Manage Bookings
           <ul id="submenu2">
              <li class="child-element"><a href="itineraries.html">Itineraries</a></li>
              <li class="child-element"><a href="flights.html">Manage my Flights</a></li>
              <li class="child-element"><a href="hotelbookings.html">Manage Hotel Bookings</a></li>
              <li class="child-element"><a href="travel-documents.html">Travel Documents</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
            
          <li class="parent">Support
            <ul id="submenu3">
              <li class="child-element"><a href="support.html">Customer Service</a></li>
              <li class="child-element"><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
              
         </ul>
        </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste ALL of the code into the snippet box

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I came up with this code, will it work well?? It worked for me on Boostrap Studio.

changed html li.parent elements to:

```
<li id="account" class="parent">Account
<li id="bookings" class="parent">
<li id="support" class="parent">Support
```

I added an id to each parent li. Also, each of its submenu has an id (#submenu1, #submenu2, #submenu3).

This is the script i used to keep the submenu open while I'm clicking anywhere inside it, and closing it if i click a different parent or anywhere else in html file.

```
$('html, .parent').click(function() {
$('#submenu1').hide();
});

$('#mainmenu, #submenu1').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#account').click(function(event) {
$('#submenu1').toggle();
});



$('html, .parent').click(function() {
$('#submenu2').hide();
});

$('#mainmenu, #submenu2').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#bookings').click(function(event) {
$('#submenu2').toggle();
});



$('html, .parent').click(function() {
$('#submenu3').hide();
});

$('#mainmenu, #submenu3').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#support').click(function(event) {
$('#submenu3').toggle();
});
```